# Django Post request works with chrome but not with firefox

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome, firefox, post

i have this project that seems to he working fine except for 2 things.
When i do a **POST REQUEST** (after some ajax calls before):
**first:** i get a `error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe` on my Chrome Version 25.0.1364.172 but everything seems to work fine still.
**second:** in firefox 19.0.2 nothing happens.. it adds the `csrfmiddlewaretoken`  in my url and shows 200 and reloads the page with my javascript action, but nothing seems to be actually done in the django side.

CODE:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="appName">App Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="appName" placeholder="App Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="appDescription">App Description</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea id ="appDescription" placeholder="App Description" rows="3"</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="create" onclick="createCity('create','user')">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$.post(url, { city_id : city_id ,type : type, city: cityStr, pois: poisStr, poisdelete: poisDeleteStr, kmz: kmzStr,kmzdelete : kmzDeleteStr,limits : limitsStr, limitsdelete : limitsDeleteStr, area_name : area_nameStr , action : actionStr , imageReplace : imageReplaceStr}, function(data,status) {
    if (data=='city_already_exists')
        alert(data);
    else {
        /*var username=window.location.pathname.split("/");
        window.location = "/"+username[1]+"/smarturbia/cities";*/
        alert(data);
        location.reload();  //otherwise does not work with firefox
    }
});
```

Django:

```
class CreateCityView(LoginRequiredMixin, JSONResponseMixin, CheckTokenMixin, CurrentUserIdMixin, View):

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CreateCityView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         ...

return self.render_json_response(city_json)
```

How can a post work in chrome and not in firefox?? what should i do to get it working on both?

Comment: Could you post your code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by changing the  to  in the html.. small mistake, big problem..